# reflection from a string , can not find the method - c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm doing a method that needs to instantiate the object model automatically .
The fact is that it fails to instantiate the object because it says it can not find .
But I assure you that the method is present .

Error:

> Could not load type 'tbl_customer' from assembly 'DataModules,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I use this:

```
string className = "tbl_customer";
string namespaceName = "DataModules";

var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(namespaceName, className);
```

else, to test the functionality instance the object directly and this works:

```
tbl_customer t = new tbl_customer();
String tmp = Type.GetType().toString();
```

doing so I work , why?
I would be dynamic .

```
var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(namespaceName, className);
```

in short, is not the method in DataModules

help me :)

Comment: Note that `Activator.CreateInstance` does *not* take a namespace and a type name, it takes an assembly name and a type name. What is the name of the assembly that class resides in?

Comment: the class is inside the model.edmx, and the namespace is DataModules

Comment: And is that in the currently executing assembly?

Comment: i have edit question with image of solution, help you ?

Comment: Not really.. let me rephrase the question: is the code using `Activator.CreateInstance` in the same assembly as the type you're trying to instantiate?

Comment: no no is a windows service , the instance that I want to call it is in another project of the solution

Comment: Alrighty. Then Niels's answer is the way to go!

Comment: I got lost in a glass of water ! I solved says niels .
Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `Assembly Name` and then the full `Type Name`:

```
string className = "DataModules.tbl_customer";
string assemblyName = "DataModules";

var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, className);
```

Comment: Seems like `namespaceName` there should be called `assemblyName`..!

Comment: Shot @Chris. Someone changed it on my part :)